# What is the meaning of JAAS error Login Failure: all modules ignored

Tags: java, jetty, jaas

I am trying to setup an authentication based on property file using JAAS on jetty.

It seems my login module is being loaded and used but i get this Login Failure: `all modules ignored` ... and i simply do not get it ... what does it means?

I have a loginConfig.jaas file

> jettyLogin {
>       org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
>       file="credentials.props";   };

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the only module you configured (and flagged required) to authenticate, returned false (auth failure). No other modules were available to succeed

Not sure how to suppress the jetty log though - I'm researching that right now